# Communication between javascript and GWT code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt

I've created a map using google maps v3 api for GWT. I'm trying to present a kml over this map, but this is not possible because it is stored locally. So, I'm trying to use geoxml3 in order to parse my local kml.

I need the javascript code to be able to "see" the map I created using GWT. How can I do this?

I create the map using

map = GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
(map_canvas is a div in my html page)

I want to call a Javascript function in order to parse the KML file and present it on my map. I know how to call a JS function but I don't know what to write in its body.,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is coding basics of JSNI from GWT documentation.  This definitely help you how to write body of the function.

Comment: well I've seen this (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#writing) but I still can't get it. I'll try passing my KML to Javascript as a String and then parse it with geoxml

Comment: Have you seen this http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted

Comment: Yes, this is the one I'm using. I managed to present my kml, calling a js function from my gwt project. however, i can't see the map, only the shape of my kml.

Comment: I managed to use JSNI as mentioned here (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI). Thnx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I plotted local kml files in gwt/gxt google maps api v3
Find and download geoxml3.js and ProjectedOverlay.js on the internet.
in your html put:<

script type="text/javascript"
 src='YourServicePath/geoxml3.js'>

Add some procedures to call the kml operations to your client entry java file:

```
public final native JavaScriptObject createKmlParser(JavaScriptObject mapId) /*-{
var myParser = new $wnd.geoXML3.parser({map: mapId});

    return myParser;
}-*/;

public final native void showKml(JavaScriptObject parser, String kml) /*-{
    parser.parseKmlString(kml);
}-*/;

public final native void hideKml(JavaScriptObject parser) /*-{
    parser.hideDocument();
}-*/;
```

Because ProjectedOverlay.js needs Google maps connected we'll inject it after we connect to Google maps.

```
mapWidget = new MapWidget(opts);

ScriptInjector.fromUrl(
    GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "YourServicePath/ProjectedOverlay.js").setCallback(new Callback() {

@Override
public void onFailure(Object reason) {
    System.out.println("Script load failed");
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(Object result) {

}
}).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();

To show the KML:
public JavaScriptObject parserGeoXml3;

if (mapWidget != null) {
    JavaScriptObject jsoParser = createKmlParser(mapWidget.getJso());
         parserGeoXml3 = jsoParser;
    try {
        showKml(jsoParser, kmlStr);
        } catch (JavaScriptException jse) {

        }
}
To hide:
try {
    hideKml(parserGeoXml3);
} catch (JavaScriptException jse) {

}
```

Comment: Looks like a very nice example but not sure why it is not working for me..project builds fine but KML won't show up..